# Tomcat 9 Spring MVC Application JS Files are downloaded with header text/html instead of application/javascript

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, model-view-controller

[image: UnCaught Syntax Error]
The javascript file is downloading  with content type text/html. instead of application/javascript as header. That's why this error is coming. Am not sure why it is adding this header.
Attached the [image: capture request from fiddler]

[image: HTML CODE]

Comment: So the path to the jquery file is being served up by Spring, not just Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first forward slash from the path of the javascript

Leaving the first forward slash indicates that there is a servlet mapping to that path, but you are only trying to load static content.

Also, make sure you have resource handlers

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }
}
```

JS files should be in `webapp/resources/js`

Comment: Show the folder structure and resource handler if you have one